# Proof of an algebraic inequality

Tags: inequality

Show that for $A,B,C \in \mathbb{R}$ and $A,B,C \ge 0$ that $A \le B + C \implies \frac{A}{1+A} \le \frac{B}{1+B} + \frac{C}{1+C}$

Comment: There is no need to write the problem twice, so I changed the title. Anyway, you should show your attempts.

Comment: the question is missing context? I want to be a polite, respectful user here. This is a math Q&A site. I asked a question, I got an answer, that is it. I don't see what extra context is desired or requested.

Comment: You did not show what you tried, that is mainly why your question has been closed. You should not post a problem waiting for a solution, this is not the aim of the website.

Comment: Is there an official guidebook on that? If I'm having trouble getting started on a problem, am I not supposed to use this site? I love the high quality user base and expertise here. I'm like to make use of this service responsibly and respectfully.

Comment: I suggest you read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Observe $\dfrac{B}{1+B} + \dfrac{C}{1+C} \ge \dfrac{B}{1+B+C}+\dfrac{C}{1+B+C} = \dfrac{B+C}{1+B+C} \ge \dfrac{A}{1+A}$. This last one is true since $B+C \ge A$.

Comment: To make it more explicit: $\frac{B+C}{1+B+C}=1-\frac1{1+B+C}\geq1-\frac1{1+A}=\frac{A}{1+A}$.